# How can I echo out the value stored in my radio button from my database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to echo out the current value of the gender of particular data and edit the gender if the user want to. How can I do that with this code?

Here is my code:

```
    echo "Gender: <label class=\"radio-inline\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Male\" > Male</label>
                  <label class=\"radio-inline\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Female\"> Female</label><br/>";
```

Below is the whole code for how I get all the information in my database:

```
       <?php 
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)) {
        echo "First Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$first_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Middle Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$middle_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Last Name: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$last_name\"><br/>";
        echo "Age: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$age\"><br/>";
        echo "Birth Date: <select name=\"month\"  style=\"width:auto;\">
                          <option value=\"$month\"></option>
                          <option value=\"January\">January</option>
                          <option value=\"February\">February</option>
                          <option value=\"March\">March</option>
                          <option value=\"April\">April</option>
                          <option value=\"May\">May</option>
                          <option value=\"June\">June</option>
                          <option value=\"July\">July</option>
                          <option value=\"August\">August</option>
                          <option value=\"September\">September</option>
                          <option value=\"October\">October</option>
                          <option value=\"November\">November</option>
                          <option value=\"December\">January</option>
                          </select>
                          <select name=\"day\" style=\"width:auto;\">
                          <option value=\"\"></option>
                          <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                          <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                          <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                          <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                          <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                          <option value=\"6\">6</option>
                          <option value=\"7\">7</option>
                          <option value=\"8\">8</option>
                          <option value=\"9\">9</option>
                          <option value=\"10\">10</option>
                          <option value=\"11\">11</option>
                          <option value=\"12\">12</option>
                          <option value=\"13\">13</option>
                          <option value=\"14\">14</option>
                          <option value=\"15\">15</option>
                          <option value=\"16\">16</option>
                          <option value=\"17\">18</option>
                          <option value=\"19\">19</option>
                          <option value=\"20\">20</option>
                          <option value=\"21\">21</option>
                          <option value=\"22\">22</option>
                          <option value=\"23\">23</option>
                          <option value=\"24\">24</option>
                          <option value=\"25\">25</option>
                          <option value=\"26\">26</option>
                          <option value=\"27\">27</option>
                          <option value=\"28\">29</option>
                          <option value=\"30\">30</option>
                          <option value=\"31\">31</option>
                          </select>
                          <input type=\"text\" value=\"$year\" size=\"3\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\"><br/>";
        echo "Birth Place: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$birth_place\"><br/>";
        echo "Gender: <label class=\"radio-inline\">
              <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Male\" ";
              if($gender == 'Male') { echo 'Checked';}
              echo " > Male</label>
              <label class=\"radio-inline\">
              <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Female\" ";
              if($gender == 'Female') { echo 'Checked';}
              echo "> Female</label><br/>";
        echo "Marital Status: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$martial_status\"><br/>";
        echo "Religion: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$religion\"><br/>";
        echo "Nationality: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$nationality\"><br/>";
        echo "Email Address: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$email_address\" size=\"35\"><br/>";
        echo "Address 1: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$address_1\"><br/>";
        echo "Address 2: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$address_2\"><br/>";
        echo "Course: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$course\"><br/>";
        echo "School Graduated: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$school_graduated\" size=\"65\"><br/>";
        echo "Remarks: <input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none; border-color: transparent;\" value=\"$remarks\"><br/>";
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo "<center><a href=\"view_all_crew.php\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" >Cancel</button></a>&nbsp;";
        echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick=\"document.location = 'edit_crew.php?id=$id'; \">Continue</button></center>";
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: Your fetch should store it's result in a variable so you can read it. It's an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if condition in radio button to select your stored value like

```
$gender = 'Female';
echo "Gender: <label class=\"radio-inline\">
               <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Male\" ";
               if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'Male') { echo 'checked';}
 echo " > Male</label>
              <label class=\"radio-inline\">
              <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"Female\" ";
              if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'Female') { echo 'checked';}
  echo "> Female</label><br/>";
```

Comment: sorry but nothing happended

Comment: Did you replaced the variable `$gender` and values `'Male'/'Female'` with your variable and values? Add your php code in the question and tell us how you store the value in database.

Comment: your value is exactly the same as your example

Comment: I just assigned value like  `$gender = 'Female';` and run the code and it's working for me. I don't know why it is not working for you. Try  `echo $gender;` to check the stored value

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you stored 1 for male and 0 for female in your database table then then the code fetched from your database can be implemented as :

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php echo $row['gender'] === '1' ?'checked="checked"':'';?>/> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php echo $row['gender'] === '0' ?'checked="checked"':'';?>/> Female
```

Thats it. If male is stored in the database then first one will be checked else second one will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this use single quotes for echo and use double quotes for values its easy to do .

```
    <?php

    $gender = 'Male';

    echo 'Gender: <label class="radio-inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"';
                   if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'Male') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }
     echo ' > Male</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" ';
                  if(isset($gender) && $gender == 'Female') { echo 'checked="checked"'; }
      echo '> Female</label><br/>';

    ?>
```